# Teen girl refuses to wear skimpy superhero costume. Probably a 90's X-Men comic

Tags: story-identification, comics, x-men

I'm struggling to locate a comic panel in which a teen girl in casual clothes is being offered her choice of superhero costumes by an older teen girl. She's appalled by the first choice (some sort of skin-tight leather outfit with incredibly high-cut legs and a very revealing neckline, [kinda like Psylocke's](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/72/63/54/726354dc9706c1a9a7ae0e652d9dafdc.jpg)) which she clearly feels is overly sexualised.

She says something like "I am not wearing *THAT* in public!". Later on the page she settles on a more modest costume.

Comment: I'm assuming if this were from *The Incredibles* you wouldn't need to ask, but it came to mind immediately when I read this.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - No, I have a very distinct memory of it being a comic. The female protagonist was either looking at the offending suit on a screen or holding it up.

Comment: Did you by any chance read Mark Waid's Legion run in the 90s? This sounds like the kind of shenanigans Shrinking Violet and Kinetix were getting up to all the time. I haven't found an image yet, but Legionnaires 23 "Girls Night Out" story seems like a possibility.

Comment: I seem to remember Kitty Pryde from the X-Men (known as Sprite at the time) going through a scene like that before settling on a costume, but that would have been early 80's, not 90's

Comment: @IchabodE - if you can find it, post it. I'm basing the 1990s description on the art style but some of the early 80s stuff has surprisingly clean lines, especially if it's been remastered for posting.

Comment: I vaguely recall something like that from The New Teen Titans, not 100% sure though.

Comment: This article has a fairly comprehensive set of costumes she's used. At least 2-3 sexy ones, but she wasn't the one rejecting them...

https://13thdimension.com/the-crazy-costumes-of-kitty-pryde/

Comment: When first seeing this on HNQ, I expected it to be from parenting.se.

Comment: It might be worth adding a note in the question (or a mod note) that some images in answers may not be safe for work. (They're totally appropriate to the question/answer, I don't think they should be censored in any way, but a head's up about what's "below the fold" might be useful to some folks.)

Comment: @1006a - I think it should be entirely clear from the title of the question that the answers may be NSFW (PG-13).

Comment: @Valorum I don't visit this SE much, and the ones that I do don't come with illustrations very often, so I was taken unawares (I'm at home, so it didn't matter to me). This is likely to be on the HNQ list, so I doubt I'll be the only one.

Comment: Could it be Storm's reaction to her costume in Ultimate X-men 1? I don't have my copy on hand to be sure so its just a comment.

Comment: @KevinMilner - I've just had a look and this isn't it. Also, she might be grumpy about her outfit being quite revealing but her "pre-superhero" outfit is hardly what you'd wear to Sunday School.

Answer (score 24):

I think you're thinking of [Starlight](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/starlight/4005-51100/) from *[The Boys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boys_(comics))*

[image: Starlight and costume suggestions] (click to enlarge)

[image: Revised costume]

Comment: No, this isn't it. She was getting her very first costume, I think, not changing an existing one. Very similar feel to it though.

Comment: and I distinctly recall she *refused* the costume rather than accepting it

Comment: Ah well, it was worth a try. :)

Comment: Definitely worth a try and worthy of an upvote, just not the right one.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots maybe try posting the bit later in the comic where they try to get her to wear the even newer costume and change her backstory to something more edgy.

Answer (score 11):

Not likely to be what you are thinking off, but the pornographic webcomic [Curvy](http://www.c.urvy.org/?date=20111224) has "Costume Designer Man" design an outfit for "Slurve" that she does not appreciate.

NSFW:

> [image]

Comment: Not what I was thinking of. This was in colour. Still worthy of an upvote though.

Comment: I've added a warning that this webcomic has a lot of pornographic content. Keep in mind that Stackexchange is generally considered a "work-safe" network.

Comment: I don't remember that last panel being that explicit... I don't know if it was changed, or if I just misread the panel as her having a sheer shirt on rather than being topless.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - She's not topless, that's merely a shirt that shows the outline of her nipples.

Comment: @Valorum: Oh, that's good to know. Just looking at it now, I was convinced she was entirely topless now. Guilty thinking from glancing at the answer at work. :-P

Answer (score 11):

Firestar did this. She was taken out of her normal outfit and given a revealing costume that she kinda freaks out about.

[image]

Comment: This is Avengers Assemble Vol. 1 (full panel [here](http://img.over-blog-kiwi.com/0/55/66/77/20150714/ob_9cc582_3.JPG)). It's close enough that I suspect that it's referencing the scene that I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 8):

Just to run down the list, could it be where Illuminia offers a slingshot bikini to Val, aka Sidekick Girl, in [this comic](https://sidekickgirl.net/costume/)?

[image: Illumnia offers a slingshot bikini costume to Val, aka Sidekick Girl]

Comment: No. Definitely an example of the same trope, but the one I'm remembering was a professionally drawn comic with perspective and art colouring.

Answer (score 7):

Could it be the [costume tryout montage](https://io9.gizmodo.com/we-can-never-go-home-comic-mocks-even-more-female-super-1724120191) from the comic *We Can Never Go Home*?

[image]

[image]

Comment: OP specified it was probably from the 1990s. *We Can Never Go Home* was released in 2015. That is a significant (and unlikly) difference.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't it. Quite a similar feel to it though...